# Unboxing object

Tags: asp.net, json, webforms, deserialization

I have a web method that accepts object

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetObject(object data)
{

}
```

Also, I have 2 classes:

```
class ConnectionString
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public DatabaseType DatabaseType { get; set; }
}

class Path
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public bool IsNetwork { get; set; }
}
```

On client side, using javascript, i defined 2 similar classes as well:

```
function ConnectionString() {
    this.ConnectionString = '';
    this.DatabaseType = 0;
};

function Path() {
    this.Path = '';
    this.IsNetwork = false;
};
```

Now, according to user decision, he can ether choose to create log in database or file system. When I send data to the method, my object resulted as null. If I create method
for each object, it works. Is there a way to unbox or desirialize from OBJECT type to ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two method overloads that each take in one of the possible classes. In the current implementation the engine does not know what classes should be put in the WSDL...

If you are using WCF you could use [`[KnownType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute to specify which classes your method supports.